# Bug: Can't de-favorite a (locked, closed, migrated) question

Tags: bug, status-completed, bookmarks

I can't remove [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077144/network-manager-keeps-creating-dhcp-connection-closed)  from my favorites. (Favorite count decreases, but returns to previous value on refresh.)

The question is locked, closed, and migrated so I imagine one or a combination of these is the cause.

I can't remember for sure, but I think the favorite count was 3 before I tried to remove it, and it is now 1. Coincidence, or have I de-favorited the question for others somehow?

Comment: Happened to me on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88947/what-should-the-users-of-stackoverflow-be-called-closed which is also closed, locked and migrated. +1, this is annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed in the next push.